# How to fix misaligned closing x symbol in this alert box?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

After adjusting the line height, the closing `x` mark to the right aligns closer to the bottom of the alert message box. I'm using Bootstrap v5.0.1. How do I vertically center the `x` mark? Thanks.

**CSS:**

```
.alert {
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  height: 45px;
  line-height: 45px;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
  Success! Your application was submitted!
  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mt-2` for `margin-top: .5em;` on your `button`.

```css
.alert {
  line-height: 45px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
  Success! Your application was submitted!
  <button type="button" class="btn-close mt-2" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>
```

Side note - setting a `height`, `line-height`, and `padding` in Bootstrap is a little redundant. You should use [Bootstrap Text Utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/text/) to replace your CSS. For example, `lh = line-height` and `fs = font-size`.

Comment: I'll check out Bootstrap Text Utilities. Thanks.

Comment: it's not a good idea to change margin. you'll have issue on responsive mode. my suggestion is that you can use flex

Comment: @gokhancevik I respectfully disagree on the margin. I use flex everywhere I can, but it's just not necessary here.

Answer (score 2):

You can just change de .btn-close height. I tried some height, and i found that acceptable.

```css
.alert {
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  height: 45px;
  line-height: 45px;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.btn-close {
  height: 5px;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't fix bootstrap with more CSS.

Comment: Yes, i would say that, but he already changed. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to overwrite an exitsing bootstrap class, you can add your own, and overwrite the padding like this:

```html
    <style>
        .alert {
          margin-bottom: 1px;
          height: 45px;
          line-height:45px;
          padding:0px 15px;
          font-size: 15px;
        }
        .alert >.extra {
            padding: 0.8rem 1rem;
        }
      </style>

    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
            The activator phrase was successfully registered!
            <button type="button" class="extra btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
     </div>
```

Comment: the selector `.extra.btn-close` would work fine too, in case you want to use this not just within the alert element